# Menu Bar Responsive, overlay with other elements

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to make a responsive menu bar and when the width is under 550px for example, the menu items overlay with the divs that are following next. What am I doing wrong?

In the CSS I tried to make the list position relative, but the same result.

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="navbar">
   <h2>Aripile Zarandului</h2>
      <ul id="ulNav">
         <li class="current"><a href="#">Acasă</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Despre noi</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Fotografii</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contacteaz&#259;-ne</a></li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#ulNav li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  line-height:3em;
  display:inline-block;
}
#ulNav li:hover{
  background-color:#2980b9;
}
#ulNav li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-size:1em;
  display:block;
}
/* Responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  #ulNav li {
      display:block;
      text-align:center;
      position:relative;
  }
  #ulNav{
    float:none;
  }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc8m6.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output? Because it works fine for me.

Comment: I posted the screenshot in the post. I want the following div to be alligned with respect to the last item of the menu bar.